# Will disassembling and re-building a computer trigger Bitlocker?

Tags: bitlocker

I have been provided with a Bitlocker-protected computer by my company.

The computer is a normal x86 PC with a fairly old motherboard - the Bitlocker key is stored in an external usb stick.

I would like to move my computer to a different place, but I would need to disassemble it to do that (the chassis is huge and wouldn't fit as cabin luggage on a plane).

I was wondering if disassembling the computer and then putting the components back together would lock it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would lock it.

No, that's not even a thing that BitLocker does. It is not a "tamper seal" but ordinary disk encryption software – as long as you have the encryption key, you can unlock it. It doesn't even have to be the same machine.

Newer systems use a TPM chip to hold one copy of the key (with the numeric "recovery key" being the other copy), where the TPM expects specific configuration to match (primarily: Secure Boot being enabled), but the same still applies – even if the TPM refuses to give out its copy of the key, having another copy on your USB stick is still enough.

(But if you have the key on a USB stick, then you're definitely *not* using a TPM, anyway.)

---

On systems where a TPM is present, the TPM chip *itself* is minimally tamper-protected (if it's a discrete chip to begin with), but that doesn't extend to the rest of the system. In particular it doesn't know whether the chassis has been opened or similar things; it will continue working as long as you don't try to outright remove it from the motherboard. (Many newer desktops have the TPM functionality embedded into the CPU instead.)

Comment: Thank you very much! A small followup question - is it possible to copy the key from a USB stick to another and use them interchangeably? Would that cause issues?

Edit: yup, the mobo is not new enough to have a TPM chip, that's the reason they had to resort to external sticks

Comment: If you have a `.bek` file on a USB stick, then it's literally _just a file_ – the unlock process doesn't look at the rest of the USB stick, only at the file's contents, so you can copy it anywhere you want. (That's not very secure, but I think the docs call it a "recovery" key for a reason – they only envisioned the USB key being stored in some safe location, not being used daily...) Things like USB-based FIDO keys or smartcards/eTokens would not be copyable, but BitLocker can't really use those anyway.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again!